# Swift: kill receiver after present

Tags: swift, quickblox, receiver

I use below code for receiver in `ViewControllerChat`:

```
func chatDidReceive(_ message: QBChatMessage) {
    print("REC")
}
```

If I go to go `ViewControllerChat` from `ViewControllerHome` and I receive chat, print once REC for me

If I go to go from `ViewControllerChat` to `ViewControllerHome` by below code and back to `ViewControllerChat` and i receive chat, print twice REC for me:

```
let goController: UIViewController mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerHome")
self.present(goController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is my plan:

1- From home I go to chat

2- In chat I receive once REC

3- I go to home by present

4- I back to chat from home and receive twice REC

If I open several times chat, I get several times REC

But I want after present `ViewControllerChat`, my `chatDidReceive` killing!

Comment: Can you show how you're calling `chatDidReceive` or how are you initiliazing `QBChatMessage`?

Comment: @DionizB i only delegated `QBChatDelegate`, `QBRTCClientDelegate`

Comment: I think you need to check if you assigned the delegate to `QBChatDelegate`, and only if delegate is not assigned then set delegate to it

Comment: @DionizB how i can check assigned?

Comment: Share how did you add your `delegate = self` and I will explain you properly

Comment: @DionizB this is my code : `QBRTCClient.initializeRTC()`
        `QBRTCClient.instance().add(self)`
        `QBChat.instance.addDelegate(self)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to dismiss `ViewControllerChat` try to remove delegates: 
       `QBRTCClient.instance().removeDelegates`

Since the cause of receiving multiple times the same message should be the way you assign delegates in every `ViewControllerChat` load. Maybe creating a specified service for implementing this would be better.